# How can i make two values constrain each other consistently?

Tags: c++, arduino, constraints

I have two variables, `static int16_t min` and `static int16_t max`.

I want them to [constrain](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/constrain/) each other, so that

- `min` is never greater than `max`, and
- `max` is never less than `min`.

Also, each value needs to be restricted within the value range of 0 - 15 (The variables are declared as int16_t since they're used for several purposes, besides the range in this particular instance).

I tried the following code:

```cpp
min = constrain(min, 0, max);
max = constrain(max, min, 15);
```

This works as intended for `min`'s value, meaning: once `min` is increased up to `max` it won't increase beyond the value of `max`. On the other hand, when the value of `max` is decreased to a value equal to `min`, it keeps reducing both values until they're both down to 0.

I have a hard time figuring out how the logic can be solved, and would appreciate any advice **that makes the logic consistent for both values**, so in other words I'd be fine with a solution that either makes:

- each value pushing the boundary of the other, or
- each value being a hard constrain for the other.

Comment: What values should they take if they are inconsistent with your constraints?  Ie, if min > max, should min become max or max become min?  Note that eitger answer can make simultanious movement of min/max impossible; suppose they are both 0, and you want them to be (1,2).  If you move min up first you cannot (it is more than max).  So you get (0,2) instead of (1,2).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Encapsulation.

What you describe is an invariant. Invariants are guaranteed by user defined data types by encapsulating the private data and only provide the user access to methods that have the invariant as post condition.

Only to outline the idea:

```
class min_max {
    int min;
    int max;
    void normalize_min() {  if (min > max) min = max; }
    void normalize_max() {  if (max < min) max = min; }

public:
    min_max(int a,int b) : min(std::min(a,b)), max(std::max(a,b)) {}
    void set_min(int x) {
       min = x;
       normalize_max();
    }
    void set_max(int x) {
       max = x;
       normalize_min();
    }
    int get_max() { return max; }
    int get_min() { return min; }
};
```

From outside the class there is no way to reach a situation where `max < min`.

Consider the comment by Yakk on your question. I wasn't sure what you actually want and for the above I assumed after calling `mm.set_max(a)` we can assert that `mm.get_max() == a` and only `min` is adjusted (vice versa for `set_min`). Other solutions are possible, for example you could throw an exception when the user attempts to set a `max` that is larger than `min`, or signal an error in a different way.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for your reply. I understand this better now, however i'm not sure i understand the `min(std::min(a,b)), max(std::max(a,b))` part of the constructor. Could you please elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: @Erik look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min (and link to `std::max` at the bottom). I was sloppy and omitted to include the `<algorithm>` header. What follows the `:` is the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). This is to ensure that no matter if the user calls the constructor via `min_max(1,2)` or `min_max(2,1)` always `min` gets the smaller and `max` the bigger value

Comment: @Erik actually I think only now I understand your original trouble. You cannot always "normalize" both values and not in arbitrary order. Thats also what Yakk adresses in his comment. As I wrote, in my code I choose to let the user only change one of the values and then adjust the other. Thats not the only way to approach it.

Comment: I haven't experimented with your code yet, but to understand your normalization issue, does the dilemma presuppose that the values are entered simultaneously? Because in practicality, they are always entered serially. Based on that - if i understand you right - one value can always be normalized based on the prior one, no?

Comment: @Erik yes of course, but consider `min = 5;` and `max = 1;` then obviously your `min = constrain(min, 0, max); max = constrain(max, min, 15);` will always adjust `min` but never adjust `max`. A `set_max_and_max` function would have the same issue

Comment: I suppose it's back to square one then : )

Comment: @Erik you just have to decide how the values should be adjusted. Putting them inside a class gives you the possibility to manage that consistently. I mean you can call `m.set_min(15);` and then `m.set_max(1);` my code will handle that, question is just what behavior you expect